# How to fix ' Disconnected, because no message in 10000 ms.' error while trying to run karma unit test?

Tags: protractor, webdriver, karma-jasmine

I am getting '**Disconnected, because no message in 10000 ms**' error while trying to run karma unit tests. This error triggered only after the installation of webdriver-manager ( to run protractor) and ran unit tests successfully before this installation.

I assumed that the error might be hitting since webdriver is up and running. So,I passed command 'webdriver-manager shoutdown' to stop it. but,it showed that no server is up and running.

My requirement is to run both protractor functional test and karma unit tests in same machine without any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution for this issue by myself.

**Solution**: Install angular cli using the command '***npm install -g @angular/cli***'. 
I am able to execute both karma unit tests and protractor functional tests in my system without any issue after installing angular cli.